# Get number of times a user has availed a particular offer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which gives information about when a particular user has used an offer. It has 3 columns

`Date`: Date at which the offer was used

`user_id`: Identifier for  a particular user

`txn_id`: Transaction id when a user uses an offer. It is always unique in the table.

The offer is such that a particular user can use it for 5 times.

**I want to know at each date the number of users are in which stage of offer usage.**

For example
On Day 1 there could be 3 users who have used offer once(redemption_1), 2 users who could have used offer twice (redemption_2).

Now on Day 2 there could be users from day 1(repeat users) as well as users who are coming for offer usage for the first time(new users).

For the new users of day 2 the logic is same as that of day 1 users.(May be 2 new users use the offer for 1 time(redemption_1), 3 new users use it for 3 times(redemption_3))

But for the repeat users now I want to add up to there previous day's usage.

For example 
On Day 1, 3 users had used offer once(redemption_1) but on day 2 if they use it one more time then they should be counted in  redemption_2.(And not in redemption_1 since they are using it for second time since the offer has started/or there last usage)

In this way I want to go on adding cumulatively the number of time a user has used a offer and the count the number of users who have used offer for 1 time(redemption_1), 2 time(redemption_2) and so on for each date

Table

```
+------------+---------+------------+
|    Date    | user_id |   txn_id   |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 2019-06-04 |       1 | 1ACSA0-ABA |
| 2019-06-04 |       2 | 1BEAA0-CSC |
| 2019-06-04 |       3 | 1AGHF0-CBA |
| 2019-06-04 |       1 | 1AVFA0-GAA |
| 2019-06-05 |       1 | 1BCFA0-AAA |
| 2019-06-05 |       1 | 1AVFB0-GAC |
| 2019-06-05 |       2 | 1AVFA0-GVA |
| 2019-06-05 |       4 | 1AVFA0-GVB |
| 2019-06-05 |       5 | 1AVFA0-BCF |
| 2019-06-06 |       6 | 1AGHF0-CCA |
| 2019-06-06 |       1 | 1BXHF0-CCA |
| 2019-06-06 |       2 | 1AGHF0-CBG |
| 2019-06-06 |       3 | 1AGHF0-CAW |
| 2019-06-06 |       2 | 1AGHF0-CTU |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

Desired Output

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    Date    | redemption_1 | redemption_2 | redemption_3 | redemption_4 | redemption_5 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2019-06-04 |            2 |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0 |
| 2019-06-05 |            2 |            1 |            0 |            1 |            0 |
| 2019-06-06 |            1 |            1 |            0 |            1 |            1 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I will walk you through the rows of output for better understanding

In row one with date `2019-06-04` there are two users who used offer once (2,3) and one user who used offer twice(1)

In row with date `2019-06-05` there are 2 user who used offer once(4,5). Note that they have never used offer before that so they counted for `redemption_1`.

In the same row there is 1 user who has used offer 2 times (2: Once on `2019-06-04` and then on `2019-06-05`) so he is counted for `redemption_2`

In the same row there is 1 user who has used offer 4 times (1: Twice on `2019-06-04` and then again twice on `2019-06-05`) so he is counted for `redemption_4`

And so on for row with date `2019-06-06`

Please let me know for any kind of clarification

Comment: Shouldn't user 3 count under redemption_1 on 06-05?

Comment: No. Why do you feel so ?

Comment: So redemption_1 is a special case, where a user is counted only once?

Comment: redemption_1 Implies he has used the offer for the first time. Not only on that day but from the inception date of the offer

Comment: Kudos for a well-done question.  Sample data and desired results as text in the question as well as a detailed explanation.  I would have liked to see your coding attempts and results, but good job nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Not a paragon of efficiency, but it works.

Test data:

```
Create Table offer_used(date DateTime, user_id Int, txn_id Varchar(50))

Insert Into dbo.offer_used (date,
                            user_id,
                            txn_id)
Values
('2019-06-04', 1, '1ACSA0-ABA'),
('2019-06-04', 2, '1BEAA0-CSC'),
('2019-06-04', 3, '1AGHF0-CBA'),
('2019-06-04', 1, '1AVFA0-GAA'),
('2019-06-05', 1, '1BCFA0-AAA'),
('2019-06-05', 1, '1AVFB0-GAC'),
('2019-06-05', 2, '1AVFA0-GVA'),
('2019-06-05', 4, '1AVFA0-GVB'),
('2019-06-05', 5, '1AVFA0-BCF'),
('2019-06-06', 6, '1AGHF0-CCA'),
('2019-06-06', 1, '1BXHF0-CCA'),
('2019-06-06', 2, '1AGHF0-CBG'),
('2019-06-06', 3, '1AGHF0-CAW'),
('2019-06-06', 2, '1AGHF0-CTU')
```

Query:

```
; With 
Dates As (Select Distinct date From dbo.offer_used OU),
Users As (Select user_id, FirstTime = Min(date) From dbo.offer_used OU Group By user_id),
UserCounts As (Select 
                 Dates.date,
                 Users.user_id,
                 Users.FirstTime,
                 UsedCount = (Select Count(*) From dbo.offer_used As Used
                              Where Used.date <= Dates.date
                                And Used.user_id  = Users.user_id)
               From 
                 Dates 
                 Cross Join Users)
Select 
  date = UserCounts.date,
  [first time today] = Sum(Case When UserCounts.date = UserCounts.FirstTime
                                 And UserCounts.UsedCount = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End),
  [2 times total] = Sum(Case When UserCounts.UsedCount = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End),
  [3 times total] = Sum(Case When UserCounts.UsedCount = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End),
  [4 times total] = Sum(Case When UserCounts.UsedCount = 4 Then 1 Else 0 End),
  [5 times total] = Sum(Case When UserCounts.UsedCount = 5 Then 1 Else 0 End),
  [bonus: never]  = Sum(Case When UserCounts.UsedCount = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End)
From UserCounts
Group By UserCounts.date
Order By UserCounts.date
```

Results:

```
date        first time today 2 times total 3 times total 4 times total 5 times total bonus: never
----------- ---------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------
2019-06-04  2                1             0             0             0             3
2019-06-05  2                1             0             1             0             1
2019-06-06  1                1             0             1             1             0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select t.date,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as redemption_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as redemption_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as redemption_3,
       sum(case when seqnum = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as redemption_4,
       sum(case when seqnum = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as redemption_5
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by t.date
order by t.date
```

Comment: I am not getting desired result [db-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/14bfd/3). I have not downvoted either.

Comment: That was me, misclick. Let me fix it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: date        redemption_1 redemption_2 redemption_3 redemption_4 redemption_5
----------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
2019-06-04  3            1            0            0            0
2019-06-05  2            1            1            1            0
2019-06-06  1            1            1            1            1

Comment: @Stu . . . I think the results from this are correct.  Every redemption is accounted once on the day when it occurs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the categories as defined are mutually exclusive, but you don't count them as such -- on the first day, for example, you count user 1 in both _1 and _2. Also, see above; _1 is actually a little more special than that. I will put $1000 of my own money down the spec was written by Marketing :-)